# USB keyboard not recognized in linux

Tags: arch-linux, usb, keyboard, input

I have a computer running Arch Linux using kernel version 4.7.6. I'm trying to use a USB keyboard with it but it doesn't seem to be recognized. The USB device is listed as `Bus 003 Device 007: ID 258a:1006` in the output of `lsusb` and it's connection is shown as `[99546.722536] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd` in the output of `dmesg`. The keyboard works fine under Windows and macOS but nothing happens when I try to type on it in Linux. Additionally, I have another USB keyboard/mouse pair that work fine in Linux. The working keyboard is listed as `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver` in the output of `lsusb` and shows up as

```
[113508.264514] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[113508.369448] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.001B: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input2
[113508.601328] input: Logitech M510 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.001B/0003:046D:1025.001C/input/input19
[113508.602329] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1025.001C: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M510] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2:1
[113508.607167] input: Logitech K350 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.001B/0003:046D:200A.001D/input/input20
[113508.607821] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:200A.001D: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech K350] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2:2
```

I can see a couple notable differences: the `lsusb` output lists a device name for the working keyboard and the `dmesg` output includes lines giving more information about the device. Beyond that, I'm not really sure what else to look at or what to do to fix this.

Comment: Are you using the unmodified stock Arch Kernel?  What is the brand/model of the keyboard that doesn't work?

Comment: @airhuff Stock kernel. It's a Redragon K552-R KUMARA keyboard. A couple of people in the Amazon reviews mentioned using it in Linux so it seems that it isn't a blanket "doesn't work in Linux" situation.

Comment: Does [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113984/is-logitechs-unifying-receiver-supported) help? You may need extra software to pair/unpair the keyboards correctly.

Comment: Update your system, 4.7.6 has not been in the Arch repos since last October.

Comment: @Wieland Thanks, that resolved the issue. I actually have been updating the system regularly, just not rebooting so the newer kernel wasn't being used...

Comment: That might also explain your issue. If you've updated the kernel package and then plug in new hardware that requires a kernel module to be loaded, the old kernel can not load that module because only modules for the old kernel exist.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It's good to understand exactly why it was happening. If you want to leave an answer then I'll happily accept it because you resolved the problem and explained the issue.